# PHP: Send MP3 to smartphone

Tags: php

I've implemented code that sends a one-time link to a smartphone. When the user clicks the temporary link an MP3 will be sent to the phone to be used as a ringtone. My code thus finds the one-time code in the database table, then "streams" the MP3 to the phone, then deletes the one-time code from the database table. Below is the central part of the "streaming".

```
while(!feof($file)) 
{
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

It basically works on smartphones, but not on iPhones. (I know, iPhones can't use MP3:s as ringtones. But it can be transformed to a ringtone.) However, it seems that (any) smartphone will call the link several times, probably some kind of pre-load, creating statistical doubles in my databases. For iPhone it doesn't work at all because the one-time code is deleted in the pre-load (?) If I remove the deleting of the one-time code it works on iPhones.

Also, I've tried it on some smartphones but sometimes the MP3 ends up just anywhere on the phone. Is it possible for the user to control where to store it somewhow? Do I need to code that?

Basically, my questions is: I want to send an MP3 to a smartphone when a one-time link is clicked on the smartphone and then delete the one-time code.

Comment: What do you want to do with the MP3 on the client side? Should it be stored? set as a ringtone? played?

Comment: First of all, you should investigate what kind of requests the clients are _actually_ making – “it seems” and “probably some kind of pre-load” are not the most helpful in properly investigating this issue. My guess would be that they probably try to make _range requests_, to use multiple parallel connections to download the content faster – and if your application is not handling that correctly, it might cause a problem. Also, proxies used by the network provider might come into play here, and could cause issues as well.

Comment: I think a real one-time link with the meaning of “make one request, and one request only” is not the most sensible way to go about this. You should perhaps rather be using a session, and allow multiple requests for clients that present a valid session id over a certain limited period of time, or something like that. And properly implemented handling of range requests may be a good idea too, for clients wanting to use multiple connections, or maybe simply resume a download that got interrupted for some reason.

Comment: @ferdynator I want the MP3 to be stored in a folder and then the user can set it as a ringtone.